# How to ignore a syntax error in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench, recursive-cte

I have created an EER Diagram in MySQL workbench 6.3.10-4. Now I need to add a stored procedure that uses MariaDB 10.2.2 functionality (which has also been released in MySQL 8.0), namely recursive CTE's. However, the syntax checker of MySQL workbench only supports up until MySQL 5.7. Because of this reason, my stored procedure gets named "procedureName_SYNTAX_ERROR" in the EER diagram, and isn't included in forward engineering.

Is there a way to ignore such an syntax error, or any other way to include this stored procedure in the export? It is no option for me to include it manually on every export (due to the many exports me and fellow developers do daily).

Comment: There will be soon the next release of MySQL Workbench which supports all (relevant) new server 8 features.

Comment: @Mike Lischke Thanks for the clarification! After seeing that there hasn't been any commit to MySQL Workbench on the MySQL Workbench GitHub I was afraid that they quit the project.

Comment: Github is only updated short after release, as we also have a commercial version of MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @MikeLischke Is there a portable (zip) version of the current release available ? It does not seem to be on the official download website...

Comment: On the download page are 2 tabs: `Generally Available (GA) Releases` and `Development Releases`. Under the latter you can find the 8.0.11 RC. Soon the GA will be available too.

Comment: @MikeLischke Thanks for notifying me!